# Github Action, getting ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, github

below if the github yml file i'm using, so basically i'm trying to create a local db so i can my unit tests but somehow i'm getting a 1045 error.  i've tried already using a no password but still fails

keeps getting

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

```
  name: Test node Jest
  on:
    pull_request:
     branches: [test]

  jobs:
    unit-test:
      name: Run Tests
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      services:
        mysql: 
          image: mysql:8.0
          env:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: localdb
            MYSQL_USER: user
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: testrootpass
            #MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: yes
          ports:
            - 3306:3306
          options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3
      steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
          with:
            node-version: "14"
        - run: npm install
        - name: Set up mysql
          run: | 
            sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
            mysql -h 127.0.0.1  -u user -ptestrootpass localdb
        - run: npm run test
```

not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: You're setting the password for the `root` user. There's a separate flag for setting the regular password.